# How to convert google chrome's cached hex version css of into normal css?

Tags: css, google-chrome, hex, hexdump

By mistake, I deleted a local CSS file and I want to retrieve it from Chrome's cache.

I found the fine in `chrome://cache/`

as `chrome://view-http-cache/http://localhost:3000/styles/main.css`

But this opens in this format [Screenshot] (Actual file is quite long)

Is there a way to convert this into normal CSS file again?

[image]

Comment: hope this can help: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2012/01/viewing-chrome-cache-easy-way.html#tabs-3

Comment: are you not able to use a hex converter to put it back into "English" (it looks like it's in English in that far right column)

Comment: @SanjeevK Thanks. this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Hope this video can help you. Not the best video, but i couldnt record it better on Windows 10... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nx-InykEqCY

All you need are Notepad and some HEX software, i was using ICY Hexplorer.

Open a file as a text, there are two HEX codes, first one for HTTP Response (short one), and the actual content (usually big one). First delete everything, except actual content text. Then use ALT key + left mouse button to remove everything at the left side (such as 00000000:, 00000010:,...), use same strategy to remove everything on the right (ASCII text of actual content; in this example it starts with @charset...), and when you are left only with HEX code (such as 40 63 68 61 etc...) replace all spaces with nothing, to get them all together (like 40636861...). Be sure there is nothing at the beginning left from something else, as well as bottom (some files wont be valid if there are several empty spaces or so). Copy that HEX code, go to you HEX software and paste is as a HEX code (dont paste it as something else, paste as a HEX; in ICY you will get ASCII on the right side, if its wrong from before, you paste it in a wrong way), go to save as, and name you file and extension (you probably know whats file extension of that file, if you dont know, take a look at the beginning of ASCII for this HEX code, if there is PNG, it should be PNG, if its MZ, its probably EXE, if its IHDR, then its probably compressed JPEG, if you dont know, Google it to be sure, but at this point you know what you are saving).